# Calculate distance between two PFGeopoints in a NSPredicate for a Parse Query

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a special case when I want to do something like

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"
    DISTANCE(\(UserLocation),photoLocation) <= visibleRadius AND
    DISTANCE(\(UserLocation),photoLocation" <= 10)"
var query = PFQuery(className:"Photo", predicate:predicate)
```

Basically, I want to `get all photos that are taken within 10km around my current location if my current location is also within the photo's visible radius`

Also, `photoLocation` and `visibleRadius` are two columns in the database, I will supply `UserLocation` as a PFGeoPoint.

Is it possible to achieve this? In my opinion, I don't think that I may call, for example, `photoLocation.latitude` to get a specific coordinate value. May I?

I'll appreciate you a lot if this can be achieved!!

Comment: you want to know how to get the distance between the two locations?

Comment: I think I have a confusing title. But I do need to calculate the distance between two points in the predicate, does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using Parse Cloud Code, here is [the quick tutorial](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide)

```
Parse.Cloud.define("latestPosts", function(request, response) {
    var limit = 20;
    var query = new Parse.Query("Post");
    var userLocation = request.params.userLocation;
    var searchScope = request.params.searchScope;
    var afterDate = request.params.afterDate;
    var senderUserName = request.params.senderUserName;
    query.withinKilometers("Location", userLocation, searchScope);
    query.greaterThan("createdAt", afterDate);
    query.notEqualTo("senderUserName",senderUserName);
    query.ascending("createdAt");
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            var finalResults = results.filter(function(el) {
                var visibleRadius = el.get("VisibleRadius");
                var postLocation = el.get("Location");
                return postLocation.kilometersTo(userLocation) <= visibleRadius;
            });
            if (finalResults.length > limit) {
                var slicedFinalResults = results.slice(0, 20);
                response.success(slicedFinalResults);
            } else {
                response.success(finalResults);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error("no new post");
        }
    }); 
});
```

The code above illustrate a basic example of how to use Cloud Code. Except, I have to make sure that all the returned image are in the union of user's search scope and photo's visible circle. There are more techniques such as `Promises`. But for my purpose, the code above should just suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I found this at the `pares.com` docs here is the [link](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#geo/iOS)

```
let swOfSF = PFGeoPoint(latitude:37.708813, longitude:-122.526398)
let neOfSF = PFGeoPoint(latitude:37.822802, longitude:-122.373962)
var query = PFQuery(className:"PizzaPlaceObject")
query.whereKey("location", withinGeoBoxFromSouthwest:swOfSF, toNortheast:neOfSF)
var pizzaPlacesInSF = query.findObjects()
```

This code fetch you all the objects that are in a rectangle area defined by the `swOfSF` & `neOfSF` objectc, where seOfSF is in the south-west corner and neOfSF is in the north-east corner.

You can make some alterations to the code and get all the objects in rectangle area that your object is in middle

i would recommend that you don't use a radius, because it will take a lot of calculations. Instead use a rectangle area (like in the code i gave you).

just calculate what is the max/min longitude & max/min latitude from your position and fetch all the objects that are in between. you can read about how to fine the min/max longitude & latitude here [Link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: what does visibleRadius mean?

Comment: if i understand it correctly, I think you did a bit of an over kill with this value. Because the fetch will only check the image if it is in the right distance from the user (i.e if the image is 20 km from the user, then you will only fetch the image if you ask for all the images in range of 20 km)

Comment: 1) discussing this might solve you architecture problem which might solve your original problem. 2) you need to fetch all the items from you to the outer circle and then use the inner circle value to sort out your elements in the app